# Impact of disabling query cache?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

Is there any way by which i can determine impact of disabling mysql query cache ?

i.e can i find how many queries are hitting the server and how many are getting served from sql cache in which sql_cache is not mentioned explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

download [mysqltuner.pl](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl) script and execute on your server.

It will show your server health, you need to check "Query cache efficiency" part for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Number of queries hitting query cache: [qcache_hits](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Qcache_hits), however I would also check qcache_inserts and qcache_not_cached status variables as well.

Number of queries executed by mysql: [queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Queries) or [questions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Questions) ( differences between the 2 are explained in the linked document)